# ROKU: DRM exception: No addon found for widevine:extra:etype:buffer when trying to play protected content

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am trying to play content using a DASH manifest with Widevine DRM based on the guidelines provided by the Roku developer forum, but it's not functioning correctly - I get a **Protected content license error.** with

```
buffer:loop:/build/work/7bee3a1850ffbe4e/os/RokuOS/System/Source/DRM/DrmEngine.cpp:DRM exception: 
No addon found for widevine:extra:etype:buffer as an error string
```

Error Code is **-6**

I initialized the native player according to the Roku manual, but it keeps throwing this error on protected content. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the response from Roku partner success DRM libraries are downloaded separately after firmware update on Roku. So, in case you did a factory reset recently and running the side-loaded app now, there may be chances that libraries are not downloaded completely. You can try for manual system software update and see if this resolves the issue. Also, try to install one channel having widevine integration (For ex. Youtube) and run that channel for sometime. If software update is not downloading those libraries, a running channel will initiate the download process. Probably this will resolve the issue.